# grails - access image in controller to use in pdf

Tags: image, pdf, grails

I'm creating a dynamic pdf with gsp and I'd like to add an image to it but I have no idea how to do this coz simply using `<img src="${resource(dir: 'images/vip', file: 'heading.png')}"/>` in the gsp does not seem to work. When creating an email you use `inline 'pic1', 'image/jpg', resourceLoader.getResource("/images/bawHeader3.png").getFile()` in the `.sendMail` so I was wondering if it's possible to do something similar for pdf. Here's what I got so far:

```
def downloadBooking() {
    def result = Booking.findById(params.id)
    renderPdf(template: "/pdf/booking/vipConfirmation", model : result)
}
```

The above works fine, I just don't know how to add an image into it. Also please show me how I would access the image inside the gsp please.

Comment: are you using "grails pdf render" ?

Comment: Not sure, I think I'm using pdfRenderingService

Comment: ok that means your using "grails pdf render"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need send the bytecode of image to "pdfRenderingService". here is configuration below.

```
//convert image to bytecode and pass it to the padf rendring service.  
def imageBytes=grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI('/images/user.png').file.bytes
```

Passing the value to pdfrendering service.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream reportBytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/pdf/booking/vipConfirmation", model: [result: result, "imageBytes": imageBytes])
```

Accessing image in template

```
<div> <rendering:inlinePng bytes="${imageBytes}" class="header-img"/> </div>
```

Comment: Hi  @L. Grobler please try this ,if you have any dought let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3.3.9

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

def assetResourceLocator
Resource resource = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('logo.png')
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/pdfs/invoice", model: [imageBytes: resource.getInputStream().bytes]) as ByteArrayOutputStream
```